# Need help on framing up the mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table records with start time,end time, duration.

Assume I have three records A,B,C where:

1. A record has start time at 2019-09-10 00:12:00 and its end time at 2019-09-10 02:30:44.
2. B record has start time at 2019-09-10 17:34:00 and end time at 2019-09-10 19:34:00
3. C record had start time at 2019-09-10 22:34:00 and end time at 2019-09-11 02:30:30

Now I have to frame a query where a,b,c records to be pulled within the start time has 2019-09-10 00:00:00 and end time as 2019-09-10 23:59:59 and C record should also be counted till 23:59:59 with a duration.

I have tried but the C record is not displaying it because the end time is different.

**Query:**

```
Select 
     start_time,
     end_time,
     duration as timespent 
from 
     tablename 
where 
     userid IN(91) AND 
     'start_time' >='2019-09-10 00:00:00' AND 
     'end_time' <='2019-09-10 23:59:59'
```

Can anyone help me how can i frame it.

I am using php codeigniter has a frame work.

Comment: Whats the query you tried?

Comment: Select start_time,end_time,duration as timespent from tablename where userid IN(91) AND 'start_time' >='2019-09-10 00:00:00' AND 'end_time' <='2019-09-10 23:59:59'

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT id, start_time, CASE WHEN end_time > @end_time 
                              THEN @end_time
                              ELSE end_time
                         END as end_time
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE start_time <= @end_time
    AND end_time >= @start_time
```

If you dont know use variables try this first:

```
  SELECT id, start_time, CASE WHEN end_time > '2019-09-10 23:59:59'
                              THEN '2019-09-10 23:59:59'
                              ELSE end_time
                         END as end_time
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE start_time <= '2019-09-10 23:59:59'
    AND end_time >= '2019-09-10 00:00:00'
```

Comment: It throws an sql query

Comment: dont know what you mean

Comment: I have tried that query but it gives an sql query error

Comment: Check update. If that work then you need to learn how use variables.

Comment: I tried using the variable before commenting for the previous one but it gives me an error saying "#1064- You have an error in your sql syntax;Check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN end_time > '2019-09-10 23:59:59' THEN '2019-09-10 23:59:59' ELSE end_t at line 1".

Comment: Its a timestamp for both the fields.

Comment: the sqlfiddle works but in my database it throws the same error which I have pointed out earlier.

Comment: Syntax error mean you wrote something wrong. Either wrong name or have wrong data type. If query work on sqlfiddle should work on your db too, Are you testing direct on db or with codeigniter? Because you should test direct on db first

Comment: I am testing directly in db not through codeigniter

Comment: show me a picture then. try remove the CASE. but the case sytanx is correct

Answer (score 0):

Look for sessions witch started or ended on that day :

```
SELECT start_time, end_time, duration AS timespent
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE(start_time) = '2019-09-10' OR DATE(end_time) = '2019-09-10'
```

Comment: we are not using any sessions by the way the date comes from the user interface.

Comment: Well... don't care about the word "session", just look at the query and tell us if it's right or wrong ;)

Comment: Yes this is correct it gives me all the three records but how do we calculate the duration for the third record.

Answer (score 0):

The duration is the difference between `end_time` and `start_time`. But `start_time` must be 00:00:00 if it's yesterday and `end_time` 23:59:59 if it's tomorrow. Right ?

Use `LEAST()` AND `GREATEST()` to do something like this :

```
SELECT start_time, end_time, LEAST('2019-09-10 23:59:59', end_time) - GREATEST('2019-09-10 00:00:00', start_time) AS timespent
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE(start_time) = '2019-09-10' OR DATE(end_time) = '2019-09-10'
```

`timespent` will be a numeric, not an int.